# How to get confidence score in keras_ocr

Tags: keras, ocr

I am using keras_ocr from [here](https://keras-ocr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/using_pretrained_models.html). How to get output confidence score in this. I go through the official documentation of keras_ocr from [here](https://keras-ocr.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/) and I found that for some popular datasets they set confidence score = 1. And also I searched internet and found that confidence score functionality will be implemented in future. Currently how to get confidence score.